# Unable to set conditional breakpoint in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm, breakpoints

I am right-clicking on an existing breakpoint but see the normal *editor* context menu instead of the `conditional breakpoint` options:

[image]

I also did a search in `Actions` and found nothing:

[image]

Why is `Pycharm` not allowing  to set conditional breakpoints?   I am on `2019.3` on `macOS`.

Comment: Try resetting PyCharm?  I have the same version and os, and it works fine for me.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Are you using any themes plugins or any of that kind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried yet again and noticed something I had missed before: the first entry in the context menu says

> Show context actions

[image]

That sounded promising so after clicking on it we get the timid `Breakpoints` menu back!

[image]